# Finding the largest possible sum of one value within an array of pairs with a limit of the sum of the other

Tags: algorithm, sum

I have an array with number pairs (a,b) like:

```
[(3,2),(100,10),(85,12),(65,5),(120,25),(50,10),(35,5),(150,20)]
```

I need to find the largest possible sum of a while the sum of b is equal or under a certain value.

So for the above if we use 20 as a limit for sum of b then the answer is 200

```
[(100,10),(65,5),(35,5)]
```

being sum of a = 200, sum of b = 20.

What algorithm should I use?

Comment: this can't be done greedily. you need to exhaust all possibilities using dynamic programming techniques. Think knapsack. Only the naming is different. Or coin change. b are the weights, your sack has a limit and a is the value. maximize value.

Comment: This is **exactly** the well-studied [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: **Brute force:** At a glance I can say, if the input size is not large, then check for every subset. You can use bitmask for simplicity of the calculation.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented the algorithm, but it's very slow, because I have several thousand rows in the array. I'm currently trying to optimize runtime.

Comment: What is the upper limit of the size of the array?